# Pointer assignment versus pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance, pointers

I'm working with a data set that varies in size from potentially very small, to as large as hundreds of millions.

When working with a contiguous data set, is there any difference in functionality or performance when assigning a new value to a pointer versus using pointer arithmetic to progress to my desired location?

For example, when progressing to the next member of the data, I could simply increment my pointer by one, or assign my working pointer to that memory address (assuming I already had it for whatever reason).

Operating under Windows using Visual Studio 2012 as a compiler.

Comment: Is there a predictable pattern in which you will be accessing members of this data structure, or is going to be completely random access?

Comment: It is split into blocks of predictable data, but the distances between the blocks is not always the same. So, a little bit of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for performance, according to Andrei Alexandrescu recently ([see this link](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920), there is a link to a video of a good talk he gave there) you should prefer indexing into an array over pointer arithmetic for contiguous accesses on modern machines.

However, there is one timeless rule for optimization: **measure it**! :)

Without more information I have nothing to say re: differences in functionality other than "no".